# Whirlpool Dryer Shuts Itself Off

Tags: dryer

I have a Whirlpool LEW0050PQ dryer. The dryer works and will run a full cycle, but there is an issue getting it started. I'll set it to any dry setting and hit start. The dryer will run anywhere from 3-60 seconds and will shut itself off. Eventually after I start it enough times it will exceed the 60 second time and it will run normally for the full cycle without shutting off. This can be up to 10 times and has gotten frustrating because you have to stand by the dryer and make sure it stays running for a few minutes.

I'm a little confused as to why this is happening because the dryer isn't even running long enough to overheat. Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific dryer so am only making this as a comment, but check to make sure you have a clean/clear vent to the outside, as it could initially be overheating if it can't get sufficient air flow.

Answer (score 1):

- First (and simplest) thing to test is the door switch: If the switch is loose, as clothes hit the door, it would pop open and stop the dryer. Hold the switch with your hand while starting the dryer. If that works, tighten the switch or replace it.
- Second, check for loose connectors to the motors, controller and door switch.
- Third thing to check would be the motor capacitors; [see the user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/download/863608/Whirlpool-Lew0050pq.html) for the schematic.